# Update of array inside watch function doesnt reflect change in ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to understand strange behaviour of ng-repeat directive.Let me explain the problem.

[image]

In the first image, search box will be empty for the first time as soon as loading is complete. Then, when there is no input in the search box, I have to render all the contacts from the database.But it is not rendering.

[image]

In second image, I type 'r' in the search box and then, it should render only the results starting with 'r'. But it renders all the results. Please note here that these results should have been rendered in the former case (I mean when search box is empty). But it didn't.

In third image, I backspace 'r' in the box. It should render all the results. But it renders contact starting with 'r'. This is wrong. Actually this result should have been shown in the second case. From all the three cases, I understand that ng-repeat is working. But it renders the last result but not the current result. I even checked in the console. Update of array happens successfully. But the result rendering doesn't happen immediately. It waits until next key is pressed.

JS code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.searchfilter = '';
  $scope.searchresult = {
    result: []
  };
  $scope.$watch('searchfilter', function() {
    $scope.renderSearchResult();

  });
  $scope.renderSearchResult = function() {
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.sampleRemoteActionPageController.getContacts}', $scope.searchfilter,
      function(result, event) {

        if (event.status && result !== null) {
          console.log('$$$ result ');
          console.log(result);
          $scope.searchresult.result = result;
        }
      }, {
        escape: false
      }
    );

  }

});
```

Note: Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction - it is a remote call used in salesforce.

Html code:

```
<div id="second-container" class="container">
   <div class="Search col-xs-12" >
      <div id="second-container-row" class="row">
         <div id="second-container-input" class="col-xs-11" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Contacts" ng-model="searchfilter" ></input>
         </div>
         <div id="second-container-phone" class="col-xs-1 Phone-container">
            <img id="Phone" class="img-sizing" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularAssignment, 'searchicon.png')}" >
            </img>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="content" ng-repeat="x in searchresult.result" >
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1 third-container-profile" >
         <img id="profile" class="img-sizing" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularAssignment, 'profileicon.png')}" >
         </img>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-10" >
         <ul style="list-style-type: none;list-style-position:outside;" >
            <li> <b> {{x.Name}} </b> </li>
            <li> {{x.Title}}</li>
            <li> Comity Designs Private Ltd.</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 third-container-phone" >
         <img class="img-sizing" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularAssignment, 'phoneicon.png')}" >
         </img>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I watch ng-model 'searchfilter' and if there is change, then I call remote function to query the database for relevant `contacts.$scope.searchresult.result` - this stores the retrieved result. The result comes in the form of array. This update happens successfully. Only the problem is rendering of result immediately. Please help me if anyone knows an answer for this.

Comment: Your search method from Salesforce looks like it's doing an "in" search, not a "starts with" search. Also, I'm willing to bet that your array not clearing is because the Salesforce method either throws an exception when it's given a null value, and you aren't trapping exceptions, or more likely returns null when passed null, and you're filtering out the null return values. Since you only update if there is a value passed back, your array doesn't update for empty string.

Comment: Maurice Reeves, if there is no input in search box, then i pass empty string to a function as a parameter.then that function checks whether it is empty string or not.if so, i have a code logic that will query all the contact records.so, empty value is not a problem at all.By the way, i got a solution.that is i have wrap the statement which updates array inside $scope.$apply{function(){.......}}. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Angular may not be aware it needs to update the scope variables. The function `$scope.renderSearchResult` does not use angular $http which usually triggers a digest cycle.

Try wrapping `if (event.status && result !== null) {...}` in either a `$scope.$apply(function(){...});` or `$timeout(function(){...});`

Comment: Thanks Miles P. i used $scope.$apply().It is working.Thanks a lot